# Create a console in VB (like minecraft console)

Tags: vb.net, console

I need to create a console within my application.....
I have tried with:

```
Public Class Form1
<DllImport("user32.dll")> Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim p As Process = Process.Start("java -jar C:\Server\Minecraft\Server.jar")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)

End Sub
```

But I have only bad result

Please help me

Comment: what is a form doing in a console app?  why the javascript tag? what does `bad result` mean?

Comment: Hello, i need to create a console, this console have to print a result of a javascript but but I can not do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Process` class to launch a command prompt (cmd.exe). Then you can communicate with it using the Standard Input and Standard Output.

First declare a variable of type `Process` at form level:

```
Private WithEvents MyProcess As Process
```

And initialize it. Launch cmd.exe.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MyProcess = New Process
    With MyProcess.StartInfo
        .FileName = "CMD.EXE"
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
    End With
    MyProcess.Start()
    MyProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
End Sub
```

Then you can use the StandardInput object of the Process class to send input to it, and OutputDataReceived event  to send input and get output from it.

```
Private Sub MyProcess_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MyProcess.OutputDataReceived
    MessageBox.Show(e.Data)
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteCommand()
    MyProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("whatever command you want to send goes here...")
    MyProcess.StandardInput.Flush()
End Sub
```

This blog post shows how to build a DOS like application inside your form.

http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/launching-and-controlling-external-applications-from-vb-net-application/

I hope this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure that is quite what Gianfranco is getting at.  I think he's using the word 'console' to mean something slightly different to a DOS prompt.  Some games like Minecraft have functionality that looks very similar to a DOS console whereby a text-based console can be opened and commands entered (used by developers to test games and by players to cheat).  It's not quite the same as a DOS prompt, although maybe a true DOS console will be just as useful for Gianfranco (he doesn't actually tell us what he needs it for).

Comment: Edited the post and provided detailed explanation

Comment: Hello... i show this error: 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Error: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Pradeep Kumar is possible interact with java?
Send command ecc...?

Comment: Any program that reads from the `Standard Input` and writes output to the `Standard Output` should work. I'm not sure of Java in particular, but you may want to experiment around. Just replace `CMD.EXE` in the code with appropriate program file name. More information about the standard streams can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams